# Oracle User Management

Tags: database, oracle, oracleinternetdirectory

Does anyone have experience working with Oracle User management? Any idea if it can be easily used to register users and roles into Oracle OID? And how I can use the defined roles in my application (i.e. should I hard code them)?

Answer (score 1):

I've asked several [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192609/what-is-the-current-state-of-oracle-internet-directory) on this topic and have gotten little response.

I think the community here isn't geared so much for this and you'd be better off [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/main.jspa) at the Oracle Forums.